# Iterate over a strings array and get a new string

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an array names = ["CAT", "DOG"], I want to iterate over this array to get a new name. To get a new name compare "C" of cat with "D" of "DOG" "C" comes before "D" so first letter will be "C".

Then, we will compare "A" of CAT with "D" of "DOG", again "A" comes first, so second word will be "A". Word so far is : "CA".

Then we will compare "T" of "CAT" with "D" of "DOG", this time "D" comes before "T" so third word will be "D" and so on..

Final word will be : CADOGT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is here to solve problems and answer questions, not create code when given a brief. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: where is your specific problem? it looks, you have an algorithm wich works by hand and just need just to implement. for the beginning, take a result set, take a variable for the next compairing and iterate the length and take one character of the first array, check and assign and save the leftover character. do the same with the other array and proceed with the next index. at the and use the leftover character.

Comment: The array will always contains only 2 strings? or can be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you could

- take a result set,
- a variable for the next compairing and
- iterate the length,
- take one character of the first array,
- check and assign and save the leftover character;
- do the same with the other array/s and
- proceed with the next index.
- at the and use the leftover character.

```js
var array = ["CAT", "DOG"],
    temp = '',
    result = '',
    i,
    l = Math.max(...array.map(s => s.length));
    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    array.forEach(s => {
        if (!s[i]) { // early exit for smaller strings
            return;
        }
        if (temp < s[i]) {
            result += temp;
            temp = s[i];
        } else {
            result += s[i];
        }
    });
}

result += temp;

console.log(result);
```